# How does OpenMPI Secure SHell into all the compute nodes from the master node?

Tags: linux, ssh, cluster-computing, openmpi

First time working with OpenMPI. I am curious how the API invokes a run-time environment to run on compute nodes. I am thinking about setting up a Linux cluster of 4 or 5 nodes. I read a lot of the documentation on creating password-less ssh access for the master node. Does OpenMPI invoke a command line argument to ssh into whatever compute nodes are declared inside the --hostfile and then begin spreading tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open MPI does not add any additional arguments (by default) when ssh'ing to a remote machine.  You should just setup your ssh keys to allow password-less logins (and if you're using an ssh passphrase, set it up so that the passphrase propagates around without manual keyboard entry).

You might also want to read these two blog entries:

http://blogs.cisco.com/performance/tree-based-launch-in-open-mpi
http://blogs.cisco.com/performance/tree-based-launch-in-open-mpi-part-2

Comment: Thanks! The blogs were helpful. I plan on setting up ssh the way you mentioned. I guess I am more curious about how Open MPI actually ssh's into remote machines? Obviously we normally type ssh remote-host from the command line. Does Open MPI run a script some place in the source that executes a similar command for each remote node?

Comment: Open MPI directly fork/exec's the ssh processes; it doesn't launch a script which then invokes ssh.  Each ssh launches an "orted" (ORTE daemon) which when does the handshaking between servers and mpirun to launch the MPI processes as requested, forward stdin/stdout/stderr/etc.

Comment: The links seem to be dead, is there an archived version or alternative documents?

Comment: Which links seem dead?  The two blogs.cisco.com links still work fine for me (3 Jan 2019)...?